# code analyzer specifically for gwt code?

Tags: java, gwt, findbugs, checkstyle, pmd

I have been going through code analyzers like pmd, findbuigs. They cover many cases and seem to be great to use.
But wanted to know if there is any code analyzer specifically for gwt code?

Comment: try https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/

Comment: @Jayan I cannot find any GWT specific stuff in CodePro Analytix. Can you give a more specific link?

Comment: @Thomas:   No, I was just  speculating codepro(being owned by google)  may understand gwt better.

Answer (score 2):

You could always try IntelliJ -- it's the world's best IDE and it's free (ish). Here's the link to the [GWT support page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gwt.html).